# asp.net Core Creating DbSet for Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a generic repository which does all the usual CRUD operations

```
   public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly CmcContext _context;

    public Repository(CmcContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        Save();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        Save();
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
        Save();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Get(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties)
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbQuery = _context.Set<T>();

        //Apply eager loading
        foreach (Expression<Func<T, object>> navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
            dbQuery = dbQuery.Include<T, object>(navigationProperty);

        return dbQuery
             .AsNoTracking()
             .ToList<T>();
    }

    public T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Interface:

```
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] navigationProperties);
    T GetById(Guid id);
    void Save();

}
```

the class repository:

```
 public class Definition : Repository<Definition>, IDefinition
{

    private static CmcContext _context;
    public Definition()
        : base(_context)
    {

    }

}
```

and the call to the repository from the controller:

```
  private readonly IRepository<IDefinition> _definition;

    public DefinitionController(IRepository<IDefinition> definition)
    {
        _definition = definition;
    }

    [HttpGet("")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_definition.Get());
    }
```

which is then set up in the ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddScoped<IDefinition, Repositorys.Pricefile.Column.Definition>();

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Models.Repository<>));
```

My issue is that when i call any of the actions in the Repository is that its passing the interface in to the repository class which IDeffinition isnt in the EF model

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot create a DbSet for 'IDefinition' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue or if what i am trying to do is even possible?

Comment: You should rethink the entire design. It's *very* problematic, and even reverses the benefits of using a repository and an ORM. Why are you savingin *each and every change?* Repositories, contexts and units of work exist so you can collect all changes and save them *once*.

Comment: As for the operations themselves, `Get` prevents you from using LINQ thus making it *harder* to query, `Insert` could be replaced by for `NamedSet.Add`, Update makes sense only for *detached* properties.

Comment: As for your actual problem, ORMs deal with *entities*. An interface isn't an entity. Mapping to an interface doesn't make sense. An interface may have 100 implementations. Which class is the ORM going to use when loading data?

Comment: i understand your reasoning with the update i was going to handle this in the specific repository for which fields can and cant be updated, as for the which interface is the ORM going to use i thought that was the job of the service when adding the scope?

Comment: In your DbContext, ensure you have something like this `public DbSet<Definition> Definitions { get; set; }`